# Blazor server through k8s ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

I've written a small Blazor application which looks to work all well when containerized and when accessed through k3s port forwarding, but struggling to find a guideline on how that application needs to be *correctly* exposed via a ingress controller. To show this:

- If I run the Blazor application and access via port-forwarding (blazor routing works perfectly well etc.):

> kubectl port-forward deployment/ 8000:80

[image: blazor approot]

and page routing working as expected

[image: blazor application]

- However, when I add a clusterIP service to the deployment and connect to it through Traefik ingress controller, I get:

[image: blazor ingressroot]

and changing the route will give a *404 page not found* error

[image: blazor ingressroute]

My Ingress serviceIp and ingress controller setup:

- ClusterIP:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: driverpassthrough
spec:
  selector:
    app: driverpassthrough
  ports:
  - name: ui
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8010
    targetPort: 80
```

- ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
        - path: /passthrough
          backend:
            serviceName: driverpassthrough
            servicePort: 8010
```

Comment: may I Know if you installed [traefik ingress controller](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/user-guide/kubernetes/) itself, not only Ingress object? And if so - how exactly you did that - helm, daemonset?

Comment: k3s comes automatically with traefik service running on it, so I just utilized that service and defining ingress controller config (the yaml manifest) for it

Answer (score 0):

so in my case, I use k3s and traefik. I also have 3 replicas of my blazor server app. To make it work, I had to enable sticky session (in annotations) on the cluster ip like so:

###### Service

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: qscale-healthcheck-service
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "true"
  labels:
    name: qscale-healthcheck-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: healthcheck
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

###### Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "traefik"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: qscale-healthcheck-service
          servicePort: 80
```

This is the link where I found the annotation: [Traefik Doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/configuration/backends/kubernetes/#general-annotations)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Max_Thom. Tried the annotation on clusterIP and still having the UI bootstrap issue. But will read up a bit more on sticky sessions to see how relevant it is and why required to use (maybe in addition to other settings)

Comment: Can you try with rewrite target /$1 instead of /

Comment: Didn't work either. Still having the Bootstrap-less page displaying 'no longer respond until loaded' feedback error. I sort of put this issue on hold, because seems like I have to do a lot more of Traefik / ingress understanding at this point